# Why is the Default Parameter being used each time? Initializing classes

Tags: c++

When I printed the variables passed through, the default is printed first, followed by what I want passed. So the final result remains the same. The initialization is found in Owner.h and Owner.cpp. Variables are passed starting from the Dog.cpp. I've also tried changing my print statements to Dog.owner... but the result was the same.

**Owner.h**

```
#define OWNER_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Dog.h"


using namespace std;


class Owner {

  private:
    string name;
    int age;

  public:
    Owner(string ownerName = "Lucy" , int ownerAge = 10); // default params
    string getName();
    int getAge();
};

#endif
```

**Owner.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Dog.h"


using namespace std;

  // Getters
  string Owner::getName() {return name;}
  int Owner::getAge() {return age;}

  // Constructors
  Owner::Owner(string ownerName, int ownerAge) :name(ownerName), age(ownerAge) {
      Owner::getName();
      Owner::getAge();
  }
```

**Dog.h**

```
#ifndef DOG_H
#define DOG_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Owner.h"

using namespace std;


class Dog {

  private:
    string breed;
    int age;
    Owner owner;
    static int dogCount;

  public:
    Dog();
    Dog(string, int);
    // Getter and Setter methods
    void setBreed(string var);
    void setAge(int var);
    string getBreed();
    int getAge();
    // Other
    void printDogInfo();
    static int getDogCount() {return dogCount;}

};

#endif
```

**Dog.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Dog.h"
#include "Owner.h"

using namespace std;

  // Constructors
  Dog::Dog(string ownerName, int ownerAge) {
      Owner(ownerName, ownerAge);
      dogCount++;
  }

  Dog::Dog() {
  }


  void Dog::printDogInfo() {
      cout << "owner: " << owner.getName() << ", " << owner.getAge() << " yo" << endl << endl;
      }


int main() {

    Dog myDog1("Belle", 15);
    myDog1.setBreed("Siberian Husky");
    myDog1.setAge(2);
    myDog1.printDogInfo();


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Typo: `Owner(ownerName, ownerAge);` is incorrect. Move into the initialization list of `Dog`, and use `owner`. i.e.: `Dog::Dog(string ownerName, int ownerAge) : owner(ownerName, ownerAge ) {++dogCount; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dog::Dog(string ownerName, int ownerAge) {
    Owner(ownerName, ownerAge);
    dogCount++;
}
```

By:

```
Dog::Dog(string ownerName, int ownerAge) : Owner(ownerName, ownerAge) {
    dogCount++;
}
```

Probably, you also want to fix this:

```
Owner::Owner(string ownerName, int ownerAge) :name(ownerName), age(ownerAge) {
    // Owner::getName(); not needed
    // Owner::getAge(); not needed
}
```

Comment: That should be a lower-cased `owner` in your second code block.

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe that was the only change needed. Way too much time was wasted.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dog::Dog(string ownerName, int ownerAge) {
      Owner(ownerName, ownerAge);
      dogCount++;
  }
```

is equivalent to

```
Dog::Dog(string ownerName, int ownerAge) : 
    breed(),
    owner()
{
      Owner(ownerName, ownerAge); // Create temporary
      dogCount++;
}
```

You probably want instead:

```
Dog::Dog(string ownerName, int ownerAge) : 
    breed(),
    age(0),
    owner(ownerName, ownerAge)
{
    dogCount++;
}
```